# parseInt nor parseFloat nor string coercion nor Number() converting string to number

Tags: javascript, html, htmlcollection

I have a set of strings in my dom with the same class. I need to convert the strings to numbers and then perform a cacluation on them and return them to the screen. I have used parseInt, parseFloat, Number() and even coercion using +variable; without any converson. I show typeof as "string" in every case. I am unsure what I am doing wrong. Can someone please help me find what I am missing? Here s my html:

```
<div class="price">
  <span class="label">from</span>
  <span class="value">
    <span class="text-lg lh1em item "> $3,845.00</span>
  </span>
  <span class="value">
    <span class="text-lg lh1em item "> $3,645.00</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

and my Javascript is as follows:

```
let customPrice = document.getElementsByClassName('lh1em');

Array.from(customPrice).forEach(function(dollarAmount) {
    let withoutDollar = dollarAmount.innerText.substr(1); 
    let withoutComa = withoutDollar.replace(",",'');
    // parseFloat(withoutComa);
    let noPointZero = withoutComa.replace(/\.00/, '');
     // noPointZero * 1;
    // parseInt(noPointZero);
    Number(noPointZero);
    console.log(typeof noPointZero);
});
```

Without the typeof, I get the correct number value as a string.
How can I force this to be a number? Thank you.

Comment: Numbers and strings are immutable. Assign the conversion to a variable to be used, `noPointZero = Number(noPointZero);`

Comment: @evolutionbox was right. I needed to redeclare my variable with the number() function and it is now returning number as the typeof.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a string to an integer in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133770/how-to-convert-a-string-to-an-integer-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a space at the beginning of the text. So `substr(1)` is removing the space, not the `$`. Use `trim()` to remove surrounding whitespace.

You also need to assign the result of `Number()` at the end. It's just like all your other fixups -- it returns a new value, it doesn't modify the value in place.

To replace commas you need to use a regular expression with the `g` modifier. Replacing a string only replaces the first occurrence.

```
Array.from(customPrice).forEach(function(dollarAmount) {
    let withoutDollar = dollarAmount.innerText.trim().replace(/^\$/, '');
    let withoutComa = withoutDollar.replace(/,/g,'');
    // parseFloat(withoutComa);
    let noPointZero = withoutComa.replace(/\.00$/, '');
     // noPointZero * 1;
    // parseInt(noPointZero);
    let numeric = Number(noPointZero);
    console.log(typeof numeric);
});
```

Comment: nice round up of fixes 

Comment: for some reason, the dollar sign was removed correctly. let numeric = Number(noPointZero); was the missing ingredient. So thank you for this answer and @evolutionxbox for getting me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Numbers and strings are immutable.
Assign the conversion to a variable to be used later.

```js
let customPrice = document.getElementsByClassName('lh1em');

Array.from(customPrice).forEach(function(dollarAmount) {
    let withoutDollar = dollarAmount.innerText.substr(1); 
    let withoutComa = withoutDollar.replace(",",'');
    let noPointZero = withoutComa.replace(/\.00/, '');
    noPointZero = Number(noPointZero);
    console.log(typeof noPointZero, noPointZero);
});
```

```html
<div class="price">
  <span class="label">from</span>
  <span class="value">
    <span class="text-lg lh1em item "> $3,845.00</span>
  </span>
  <span class="value">
    <span class="text-lg lh1em item "> $3,645.00</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a space your `substr()` is getting rid of. Do `.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '')` instead.